# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: “”

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I am getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: error`

I believe the declarations are appropriate

1. I have taken input of numbers in string earlier itself.
2. The below part only calculates the sum.
3. Second part is a continuation of 1st part.

Declaration is given below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText num1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
    final EditText num2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);
    final EditText resu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.resu);
    resu.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    resu.setFocusable(false);
    resu.setClickable(false);
    final Button plus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.plus);


    final String n1 = num1.getText().toString();

    final String n2 = num2.getText().toString();
```

On click program:

```
plus.setOnClickListener(
    new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {          
            try{
              float sum = Integer.valueOf(n1) + Integer.valueOf(n2);
              String a = Float.toString(sum);
              a = a.trim();
              resu.setText(""+a);
            }catch(Exception e){
              resu.setText(""+e);
            }
        }    
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the following code inside your `onlick()` method, because in your `oncreate()` if the `EditText` is empty it will return empty String (""), so you need to get the value when the button is clicked, not before it:

```
final String n1 = num1.getText().toString();

final String n2 = num2.getText().toString();
```

To:

```
plus.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            final String n1 = num1.getText().toString();
            final String n2 = num2.getText().toString();
            float sum = Integer.valueOf(n1) + Integer.valueOf(n2);
            String a = Float.toString(sum);
            a = a.trim();
            resu.setText(""+a);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            resu.setText(""+e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: than you! this helped! however this causes code duplication for every button( suppose i have many buttons! )
How can i make those 2 lines be written once and still run properly (without using a new button)

Comment: You can use somethings like this: Integer.valueOf(num1.getText().toString()) + Integer.valueOf(num2.getText().toString()); Please mark this answer as correct if it helped you

Comment: it helped, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies on `Integer` Object to `float` primitive type conversion. I think if you give an input a Whole Number then your code should work fine. code

`float sum = Integer.valueOf(n1) + Integer.valueOf(n2);`

But if it's not a whole Number then inorder to incounter `NumberFormatException` you're failing to convert `String` into your appropriate primitive Data type.

And also check for empty String ("") in `n1` and `n2` by `if(n1=="")`

```
plus.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try
            {
               final String n1 = num1.getText().toString();    
               final String n2 = num2.getText().toString();
               if(n1==""){
                  n1="0";
               }
               float sum = Float.valueOf(n1) + Float.valueOf(n2);
               String a = Float.toString(sum);
                a = a.trim();
                resu.setText(""+a);
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                resu.setText(""+e);
            }
        }
      });
```